# How to make Input TextBox with Style Mathon?

Tags: html, css

[alt text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/1446/20091224044146.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/1446/20091224044146.png)

How cam i find and copy for this ?

Comment: What? Perhaps you could explain your requirements better.

Comment: Where are you encountering this? I can't seem to find it on the yahoo site. Maybe post the ink?

Comment: That Mathon Program in Start up page

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug in Firefox to see how Yahoo have styled their search box

Answer (score 0):

You could save the page a to the local folder, and that will being across HTML and all suppoprting files (JavaScript, js, etc)

My suspicion is that it'll be some YUI style plugin, but don't quote me on that.